# equivalent projections

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $p,q$ are two equivalent projections in $B(H)$,do $p(H)$ and $q(H)$ have the same dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $p=v^*v$ and $q=vv^*$, then $v$ is an isometry from $pH$ onto $qH$.

You have
$$
vp\xi=vv^*v\xi=qv\xi\in qH.
$$
Also, 
$$
q\xi=q^2\xi=vv^*vv^*\xi=vpv^*xi\in vpH,
$$
so $v$ is onto $qH$. And 
$$
\|vp\xi\|^2=\langle vp\xi,vp\xi\rangle=\langle v^*vp\xi,p\xi\rangle=\langle p^2\xi,p\xi\rangle=\langle p\xi,p\xi\rangle=\|p\xi\|.
$$